# Using UIScrollView, when Zooming Out, how can I keep the content view at the center?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming, alignment, center

The minimum scale is 0.5

The maximum scale is 2.0

I need to always use larger `contentSize` for `UIScrollView` to be able to drag around the content. So, as the `CGRect` of the content is changing, `contentSize` of `UIScrollView` is also changing.

However, as I zoom out, if the scale is going below 1.0, `contentOffset` is abruptly changed to {0.0, 0.0}, making it very difficult to resize the content while keep it's position to the overlay view (e.g. a clothe image).

In other words, I can't make the content view smaller while keeping it positioned at the center of the `UIScrollView`.

Please help me to find the right way to use zoom in/out with `UIScrollView` while keeping the position of the content view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions is basically about using `contentInset` at initial setup to keep the content at the center, instead of `contentOffset`. With `contentInset` being unmodified, zoomed in or out object can be at the center all the time.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered pretty well in the post:
[UIScrollView with centered UIImageView, like Photos app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638299/uiscrollview-with-centered-uiimageview-like-photos-app)

In particular, refer to JosephH's answer which itself is culled from the 2010 WWDC presentation.

This is also covered in Matt Neuburg's book, using the same WWDC reference:
[http://www.amazon.com/Programming-iOS-6-Matt-Neuburg/dp/1449365760/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1367363707&sr=8-1&keywords=programming+ios6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449365760)

The source of which is available here (see chapter 20):
https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples

The open question for me, is can this not be done as part of the constraints.