# Fix next image in scroll view like in page view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I created a scroll view , but i want to made it to act like a page view .

```
- (void)setupScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrMain {
            for (int i=1; i<=11; i++) {
                image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",i]];
                      if (i==1) {
                    imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 2, 289, 470)];
                }
                 else
                    imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i-1)*350, 2, 289, 470)];
                imgV.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
                [imgV setImage:image];
                imgV.tag=i+1;
                [imgV bringSubviewToFront:self.aleatoire];
                [scrMain addSubview:imgV];
                UIImageView *aleatoire=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake (self.aleatoire.frame.origin.x-19,self.aleatoire.frame.origin.y,self.aleatoire.frame.size.width,self.aleatoire.frame.size.height)];
                aleatoire.image=self.aleatoire.image;
                [imgV addSubview:aleatoire];
                [imgV bringSubviewToFront:aleatoire];
                UIButton *rand = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                [rand addTarget:self
                         action:@selector(randomBtn:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

                rand.frame=aleatoire.frame;

                rand.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
                rand.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


                imgV.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                [imgV addSubview:rand];
                [imgV bringSubviewToFront:rand];




            }
            [scrMain setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scrMain.frame.size.width*11, scrMain.frame.size.height)];

        }
```

but i have this issue:[image]

the next image is not in the center . Any ideea where i'am wrong ?

Comment: Have you turned paging on for the scroll view?

Comment: try this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638299/uiscrollview-with-centered-uiimageview-like-photos-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `UIScrollView` paging `pagingEnabled` property enable to create scroll behavior like pageView.

try this code :

```
scrMain.pagingEnabled=YES;
scrMain.contentOffset = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 0); // set your size to scroll content
```

Simple way to create pagerView in `UIScrollView`

```
int x = 0;

    for (int i=1; i<=11; i++) {
        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
        img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",i]];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:img];
        x = x + [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
    }
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-64);
    self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 0);
```

Comment: I set scrMain.pagingEnabled=YES;
scrMain.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrMain.frame.size.width, 0);  but it scroll too fast untill the end

Comment: your ideea it works , Thanks , Only one more question . Why is starting from the second image ?

Comment: you set x=0 ? and scrollVIew x=0, y=0, width=height=screen size @AdinaMarin

Comment: frame for image i set it like this : UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width,self.card.frame.size.height)];

Comment: yes correctly set frame, i alway use this code and work proper. I think problem in scroll u check it. @AdinaMarin

Comment: and how to detect if it;s the end of scrollView ? Because i want the carousel effect.

Comment: @AdinaMarin see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993280/how-to-detect-when-a-uiscrollview-has-finished-scrolling